# CakePHP 2 can not find plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, mongodb, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP 2 I use @[ichikaway](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/tree/cake2.0)'s MongoDB plugin like this:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'mongodb.mongodbSource',
    'database' => 'mydbname',
    'host' => 'host.mongohq.com',
    'port' => 27018,
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'secret'
);
```

I have placed it in *plugins/mongodb* yet Cake can not find it and thus can not connect.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load the plugin in the bootstrap.php file either individually or all of your plugins with CakePlugin::loadAll()

Also, keep in mind that your plugins need to be camelized, it should be Mongodb

Comment: Thanks!
For others, this fixed it:
bootstrap.php: CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');
database.php: 'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',