# Cakephp 2.0 Mongodb Plugin not loading

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to change my database over to Mongodb. I have Mongo loaded and working from the shell.  Now I am trying to get cakephp 2.0 to connect to the database.  I have downloaded and installed ichiaway's drive into the app/plugin directory as Mongodb.  I have included the line

```
CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');
```

in my bootstrap.php file.  I have changed my database.php file to

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'mongodb.mongodbSource',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'service4u',
    'port' => 27017
);
```

The database works as a service right now and I can start the mongo shell and work with the database just fine but when I try and load a page from my app I get the following error.

```
Missing Plugin
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the mongodb plugin
Error: Make sure your plugin mongodb is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded
<?php
CakePlugin::load('mongodb');

Loading all plugins: If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file

CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

I am at a loss now on what to do. I have tried putting the files in different folders inside the Mongodb folder in the plugin folder but nothing I do helps.  Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find the answer. The only thing I had wrong was in my database.php file the datasource should be camelCase. I had lowercase m's, changed them to M and it worked.

Found the answer here
[CakePHP 2 can not find plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405665/cakephp-2-can-not-find-plugin?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure downlaod file more then 2.5.if not please 
[Download mongoDB plugin for cake php.](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb)

just download and put he all file on app/plugin/Mongodb.
set database in database.php

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'blog',
    'port' => 27017,
    'prefix' => '',
    'persistent' => 'true',

);
public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'database' => 'test_mongo',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 27017,
);
```

and add blow code on bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');
```